# MonoDevelop: discover [Register]'ed classes from different projects

Tags: monodevelop, xib, xamarin, white-labelling

We would like to separate some XIBs/AXMLs and all images away from corresponding projects in MonoDevelop to get an easy-to-use white labeling feature. Having the ability to add custom build configurations and specify the projects to be built in each, we ended up with the following structure:

1. MonoToch project

   - BL
   - Controller classes
2. A type project

   - Images folder
   - XIB folder
3. B type project

   - Images folder
   - XIB folder

Having A and B configurations set up, the resulting product would use images and xibs from A or B project in the solution (same applies to Android one) overriding default ones just in case the main project contains the same files.

Everything is just perfect, but one thing: XIB files from A and B project do not see controller classes (declared in main project), which makes desining them in IB a bit of a pain.

**So, here comes the question**: how would one tell MonoDevelop to discover classes for stabs from different projects (not only the one XIBs reside in)?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the Obj-C stubs that MonoDevelop exports to dummy Xcode projects to make the Xcode designer aware of user-defined types do not currently include types from libraries.

You should still be able to *use* types from libraries but you'll have to manually type their Register'd names into the "custom class" field in the Xcode designer. Unfortunately connecting outlets and attributes would not be possible, but the designer would not remove existing connections.

A way to work around this limitation might be to *create* the xib in project 1, and set any custom types on controls, and connect outlets and actions. Next, remove the xib from that project, and copy it into projects 2 and 3. In those projects you should be able to modify properties of the controls on the xibs without breaking the outlet/action connections.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. Will try to minimize the number of xibs to be customized then...

Comment: If you're only customizing strings, you might be able to do it via the localization mechanisms. You might also consider using a script to copy and transform the xib files in a prebuild task - they're xml, and not too hard to figure out.

Comment: Actually, it is mainly images, with minor changes to layout in rare cases, so I guess it would be enough to just design xibs in main project and move them to a custom one when done.

Comment: Oh, if it's just images, you just need a different image with the same name.

Comment: Maybe there is a chance to have a patch will this functionality enabled? I can see that the built-in designer in alpha version of Xamarin studio does this perfectly, but it works with storyboards only :( And the use-case appears to be pretty common: it is obviously reasonable to share some controls, custom views etc through a library project across multiple apps...

Comment: This is not easy implement - we'd rather spend that time making our new built-in storyboard designer better, since it offers a much better experience.